# Public method outside of public class

Tags: java, class, arraylist, methods

The objective is to write code to determine the closest x,y coordinate to (24,5). Using a public class PointXY with 2 instance variables. Then a public method outside of the class that returns the point closest to (24,5). I know I'm not doing it right as the ArrayList of type PointXY is confusing me. Thank you help in advance.

```
    public class PointXY {
        private int x;
        private int y;

}

public PointXY closest_24_5(ArrayList<PointXY> b) {
        ArrayList<PointXY> nums = new ArrayList<PointXY>();
        nums.add(new PointXY(3,6));
        int total = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size();i++) {
                int dx = 24 - this.x;
                int dy = 5 - this.y;
                int thisDistance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
                if(thisDistance<total) {
                    total=thisDistance;
                }
        }
        return total;
}
```

Comment: if you're only trying to find the minimum of a bunch of distances, you don't need the call to `Math.sqrt`.  However, if you ignore my advice and do store actual distances (rather than distance squared), I don't recommend storing it in an `int` - usually it isn't.

Comment: I think you're supposed to just run through the list passed into the method, looking for the closest point. There's no need to construct your own `ArrayList<PointXY>` internally in the method.

Comment: OK, you have a variable for storing the shortest distance you've found so far, but you'll need a second variable for storing the closest point you've found so far.  This is because your method actually needs to return the point, nut just the distance.

Comment: How would I run through the list? The question asked is just confusing to me. It's an arraylist of an array list. An example is {[1,3],[2,4],[63,3]}. when doing a for loop to check this how will I distinguish x from y? using split?

Comment: The original task was:

Comment: write a public class named 
     * "PointXY" with 2 private instance variables named "x" and "y" both of type int. You may 
     * add any other functionality to this class you'd like including constructors, methods, and 
     * other instance variables*
     * 
     * Write a public method outside of PointXY (in the Problem Set class) named closest_24_5 
     * that takes an ArrayList of PointXY as a parameter and returns the PointXY that is closest 
     * to the point (24,5). Use Euclidean distance for distance measurements

Comment: You don't need to "distinguish x from y", because when you iterate through the list, you get `PointXY` objects.  So you'll go `for (PointXY aPoint : theList) {`  at the top of your list.  Then you can operate on `aPoint` within the loop.

Comment: Look, if I have time later, and nobody else writes a proper answer that shows how to iterate through the list, then I'll write one.  But it certainly won't be in the next 12 hours.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments. Not all comments are shown initially. You can't format code in comments. Make it easy for others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Java.
In Java,
there are only classes;
nothing exists outside a class.

If you have code that you want to share and for which you don't want to instantiate a class,
use a static public method.
Here is an example:

```
public class KapowThing
{
    public static void kapow()
    {
        System.out.println("Kapow");
    }
}

public class MainThing
{
    public static void main(final String[] arguments)
    {
        KapowThing.kapow();
    }
}
```

**Edit**
You can have public methods in non-public classes,
but you probably don't want that since the non-public classes will have
limited (perhaps none) visibility outside of the declaring class.

If the class has limited access,
it rarely makes sense to have a method with greater access (as in a public method in a private class).
The only time I might do this is if I have an interface and a bunch of task specific factories that all create a private class which implements the interface.
I'm not even sure that this can be done.

Here is some more code:

```
package learn.access;

public interface Thingy
{
    public void sayHello();
}


package learn.access

import learn.access.p1.MakeP1Thingy;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MakeP1Thingy.makeThingy().sayHello();
    }
}


package learn.access.p1;

import learn.access.Thingy;

public class MakeP1Thingy
{
    public static Thingy makeThingy()
    {
        return new p1Thingy();
    }
}

package learn.access.p1;

import learn.access.Thingy;

// package access class.
class p1Thingy implements Thingy
{
    @Override
    public void sayHello()
    {
        System.out.println("p1 hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant outside of the public class PointXY. As I am still writing that method in the Problem_set class.

Comment: You can have public methods in non-public classes, but you probably don't want that since the non-public classes will have limited (perhaps none) visibility outside of the declaring class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible approach.  Add a method to your `PointXY` class, for finding the distance to some other point.

```
public class PointXY {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public PointXY(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double distanceTo(PointXY other) {
        return Math.hypot(x - other.x, y - other.y);
    }
}
```

Then, in the code in some other class, you'll be able to iterate through a `Collection<PointXY>` looking for the closest `PointXY` to some specified `PointXY`.  You'll have to keep track of the closest point found so far, and the distance to that closest point.

```
public PointXY closestTo(PointXY target, Collection<PointXY> toChooseFrom) {
    double leastDistanceSoFar = 0;
    PointXY closestPointSoFar = null;
    for (PointXY aPoint : toChooseFrom) {
        double thisDistance = target.distanceTo(aPoint);
        if (closestPointSoFar == null ||  thisDistance < leastDistanceSoFar) {
            closestPointSoFar = aPoint;
            leastDistanceSoFar = thisDistance;
        }
    }

    return closestPointSoFar;
}
```